# Android NDK returns an error : undefined reference to 'rand' & 'srand'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile a shared library for 64 & 32 bit using Android NDK 19, what I couldn't comprehend is the fact that i manage to compile the 64 bit part, however it fails with 32 bit stating that both srand and rand functions are undefined, do you have any idea what might cause this problem ?

just to point out it does work when i switch to android-21 as APP_PLATFORM.

[NDK Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy80K.png)

```
Application.mk

APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

Comment: Well, looking at `stdio.h` in the NDK, `rand` and `srand` are both marked as `__INTRODUCED_IN(21)`, i.e. they were introduced in API level 21.

Comment: @Michael does that mean i'm obliged to go for android-21 ? and thank you for your reply

Comment: If you want to use those implementation rather than writing your own, then yes, it seems so.

Comment: @Michael ok thank you again for the clarification

Comment: Those functions are inline before API 21. You can still use them. It sounds more like you have a library in your build that was built for 21+ and you're trying to use it from your APi 19 build. That doesn't work. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#using-mismatched-prebuilt-libraries